# anyone know how to add command line args in vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

i have a program that runs like so:

a.out 23421232

now if i use a.out it will tell me check params and gives an example and closes.
I am curious if there is a way to add command line args when executing my code in vs2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS doesn't normally produce an executable named `a.out` like most Unix compilers do. Instead, given an input `XXX.cpp`, it'll produce an executable named `XXX.exe`.

Adding command line arguments is done by bringing up the project properties (Alt+F7), selecting "Debugging" and then entering the argument(s) in the "Command Arguments" control. There, you'll add JUST the argument "23421232" (or whatever).

Answer (score 4):

Right click the project in Visual Studio.  Click **Properties**.  On the **Debugging** page, there is a **Command Arguments** property.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the VS IDE to add parameters for running the program in the IDE, you can also open a command prompt window (Start | Run | `cmd`) and run the program the same as in Linux, except the .exe extension is optional:

```
 C:\Windows> cd "\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Applications\MyProject"
 C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Applications\MyProject> myprogram 23421232
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Project Properties window for your executable project.

Under the "Debug" section, you can specify your command line arguments.  These will be used when debugging.